# How do I make a container take 100% of the page's width?

Tags: image, css, alignment, containers

I am puzzled by what I am doing.  First take a look at my tiny snippet:

HTML:

```
 <div class="image_container"></div>
```

CSS:

```
 .image_container {
 background-image: url("images/wall.jpg");
 height: 120px;
 width: 100%;
 }
```

What I am using above was to have a container with an image as a background that will take the entire width of the user's screen since I am using width: 100%.  But on my 13 inch Mac it looks that way but when I go to a much larger screen the image shows partially but doesn't take 100% of the screen.  Why is it that despite using width 100% it still won't take the entire width?

I tried to see if I can use background-repeat: repeat-x but that simply repeats the image and it looks terrible.  What else can I do or is there another approach?

Comment: How much of the screen does it take up?

Answer (score 3):

Because you set the width for the div, not the image. Try `background-size: cover;`

Oh...and `container` should actually be `class`.

Comment: Sorry, it is class but in typing here i made a typo.  Thanks for catching it.